# Import data file and post-process using Python

Tags: python

I'm currently using Python to post-process some results from a C++ program that I wrote.  The data is stored in a csv file.  Here is the format of the data file:

```
0.1111111111
0,0,0
0.1111111111,-0.04001496601,-0.02504003688
0.2222222222,-0.0793835043,-0.04974652802
0.3333333333,-0.1171623362,-0.07381573872
0.4444444444,-0.1521229773,-0.09695208717
```

I have 4 of these data files.  For each file, I need to read the first line, store it to a variable, and then read the rest of the lines storing them to an array.  Here is how I did this (suggestions welcome):

```
nGridPts = [10,100,1000,2000]

# Setting up lists for dx vector and L2 vector
dx = [0]*len(nGridPts)
L2 = [0]*len(nGridPts)

for nPts in nGridPts:

    # Importing data 
    fname = './DataFiles/Hw2_'+str(nPts)+'pts.dat'
    dx[i-1] = np.genfromtxt(fname,skip_footer=(nPts),usecols=0,dtype=float)
    data = np.genfromtxt(fname,delimiter=',',dtype=float,skip_header=1)

    # Separating data
    x_n = data[:,0]
    phi_n = data[:,1]
    TE = data[:,2]
```

Then, I need to calculate the L^2 norm of the truncation error (TE).  This is done within the above loop as follows:

```
    sum = 0.0
    for n in TE:
        sum = sum + TE[n]**2*dx[i-1]
    L2[i-1] = math.sqrt(sum)
```

However, all that I get is sum = 0.0 and L2 = 0.0.  I've printed out the types of TE[n] and dx[i-1].  The result is

```
TE[0] type = 
<type 'numpy.float64'>
dx[0] type = 
<type 'numpy.ndarray'>
```

This is probably a simple problem, but I can't seem to figure it out.  I'm relatively new to Python.  I would greatly appreciate any feedback/pointers on where I'm going wrong.

Comment: What is the value of `i` and where is it set?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have an error in the L^2 calculation. It should be:

```
sum = 0.0
for n in TE:
    sum = sum + n**2 * dx[i-1]
```

The statement `for n in TE` iterates over the values in `TE` not the indices. Since all values in `TE` are less than 1.0, your old code kept on using `TE[0]` which is 0.0.